# justification not working properly

Tags: c++

```
    if  (ch1 = 'l' || 'L')
        cout << left;
    else if (ch1 = 'r' || 'R')
        cout << right;
    else
        cout << "error" << endl;

    cout << setw(++aw) << setfill(char(a)) << s1 << endl;

    if  (ch2 = 'l' || 'L')
        cout << left;
    else if (ch2 = 'r' || 'R')
        cout << right;
    else
        cout << "error" << endl;

    cout << setw(++bw) << setfill(char(b)) << s2 << endl;

    if  (ch3 = 'l' || 'L')
        cout << left;
    else if (ch3 = 'r' || 'R')
        cout << right;
    else
        cout << "error" << endl;

    cout << setw(++cw) << setfill(char(c)) << s3 << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why but all 3 output lines come out left justified. It seems legit to me I'm not positive if there is a logical error somewhere or if I just typed it in wrong

Comment: `then` is not a C++ keyword ...

Comment: You need to learn some basic C++, including what a *literal* value is, like the character literal `'l'`. Also, how to use multiple conditions in an AND or OR chain.

Comment: May we see the declaration of `ch1`, `left` and `right`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write e.g.

```
if (ch1 = 'l' || 'L')
```

this will always be true because you are effectively saying

```
assign 'l' to ch1  (whose result is always is != 0)
```

OR

```
if 'L' is not equal to zero (which always is !=0)
```

instead the correct way to write it is using double `=`

```
if ( ch1 == 'l' || ch1 == 'L')
```

or

```
if ( toupper( ch1 ) == 'L' )
```

Answer (score 1):

the comparison should be

```
if (ch1 == 'l' || ch1 == 'L')
  ch1 = left;
else if(ch1 == 'r' || ch1 == 'R')
  ch1 = right;
else
  cout << "error" << endl;
```

'l' , 'r', 'R', 'L' should be character literals unless you have the variables l,r,L,R with the appropriate characters assigned.